# if else statement not setting my variable in the right way

Tags: php

i have a wbsite, the user fills a form that has a from and to inputs, after the user submits and before the data enters the database, it goes through an if else statement to set a variable called price based on what the user chose from the form, but the price is being set in a weird way i don't understand it, it doesn't choose the right if statement, i checked the syntax and it looks good, what can be the problem?, and is it bad to have that many if statements? should i use another way?

```
 function newOffer(){
         
         if( $_POST['from'] == 'Irbid' || $_POST['from']== 'Ajloun' || $_POST['from']== 'Jerash' || $_POST['from']== 'Balqa' 
               && $_POST['to'] == 'Irbid' || $_POST['to'] == 'Ajloun' || $_POST['to'] == 'Jerash' || $_POST['to'] == 'Balqa'  ){
                
                $price = 1.5;
            }
            
            else if( $_POST['from'] == 'Irbid' || $_POST['from']== 'Ajloun' || $_POST['from']== 'Jerash' || $_POST['from']== 'Balqa' 
               && $_POST['to'] == 'Amman' || $_POST['to'] == 'Zarqa' || $_POST['to'] == 'Mafraq' || $_POST['to'] == 'Madaba'  ){
                
                $price = 2.0;
            }
            
            else if( $_POST['from'] == 'Irbid' || $_POST['from']== 'Ajloun' || $_POST['from']== 'Jerash' || $_POST['from']== 'Balqa' 
               && $_POST['to'] == 'Karak' || $_POST['to'] == 'Tafileh'){
                
                $price = 2.5;
            }
            
            else if( $_POST['from'] == 'Irbid' || $_POST['from']== 'Ajloun' || $_POST['from']== 'Jerash' || $_POST['from']== 'Balqa' 
               && $_POST['to'] == 'Maan' || $_POST['to'] == 'Aqaba'){
                
                $price = 3.5;
            }
            
            else if( $_POST['from'] == 'Amman' || $_POST['from']== 'Zarqa' || $_POST['from']== 'Mafraq' || $_POST['from']== 'Madaba' 
               && $_POST['to'] == 'Amman' || $_POST['to'] == 'Zarqa' || $_POST['to'] == 'Mafraq' || $_POST['to'] == 'Madaba'  ){
                
                $price = 1.5;
            }
            
            else if( $_POST['from'] == 'Amman' || $_POST['from']== 'Zarqa' || $_POST['from']== 'Mafraq' || $_POST['from']== 'Madaba' 
               && $_POST['to'] == 'Irbid' || $_POST['to'] == 'Ajloun' || $_POST['to'] == 'Jerash' || $_POST['to'] == 'Balqa'  ){
                
                $price = 2.0;
            }
            
            else if( $_POST['from'] == 'Amman' || $_POST['from']== 'Zarqa' || $_POST['from']== 'Mafraq' || $_POST['from']== 'Madaba' 
               && $_POST['to'] == 'Karak' || $_POST['to'] == 'Tafileh'){
                
                $price = 2.0;
            }
            
            else if( $_POST['from'] == 'Amman' || $_POST['from']== 'Zarqa' || $_POST['from']== 'Mafraq' || $_POST['from']== 'Madaba' 
               && $_POST['to'] == 'Maan' || $_POST['to'] == 'Aqaba'){
                
                $price = 3.0;
            }
```

for example, if i set the from to Madaba and the to to Madaba the price is set to 2.0, while it should be 1.5

after this i send it to the databse, i got the column saved as int in the table, i tried to save the column as varchar and the price inside "" but the problem stayed the same.

Comment: You're not grouping the and/or with parenthesis, so if ANY of the matches are correct, it will enter that block.

Comment: ohhh damn, thank you so much

Comment: That said, using `in_array` would make it easier to read and actually eliminate the need for parenthesis. `if(in_array($_POST['from'], ['your', 'list', 'of', 'items']) && in_array( $_POST['to'], ['other', 'list', 'of', 'items']))`